# AngularJs - Dependent Select - How to get the picked value

Tags: angularjs

so I have two dependent select, one for states and the other for cities. It works fine but I can't get the value picked in the first select. I tried everything, the only result I got was the list of all the cities. What I need is which state picked.

My code:

```
<label>States</label>
            <select id="provincia" class="form-control" ng-model="ciudades" ng-options="provincia for (provincia, ciudades) in provincias">
              <option value=''>Elegir</option>
            </select>

    <label>Cities</label>
      <select id="ciudad" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!ciudades" ng-model="modelciudad" ng-options="ciudad for ciudad in ciudades" required>
        <option value=''>Elegir</option>
      </select>
```

My list is something like this:

```
$scope.provincias = {Florida:['Miami', 'Orlando']}
```

I try using ng-model on Option tag but with no result.

Thanks

Comment: Can u provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/ this is the example that I used

Comment: Can u update with your code?

Comment: Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/hrugdavu/3/ the value of country/city selected is assigned to the model variables country and city respectively and you can use it using $scope.modelVariableName. Is this what you need?

Comment: no. That jsfiddle is not like my example... I have an object with arrays. How can I save which atributte the user picked?